# Using date with sed with repeated output from a long running command

Tags: sed, zsh

I'm attempting to prepend the a date/time to the output of a long running command on my Mac (zsh) but the date/time does not change from the initial one used in the replacement.

Use case I'm printing out a system variable from a Mac program "powermetrics", filtering the output through grep and then sed to insert the date/time for later analysis.

Command is:
`sudo powermetrics --samplers thermal | grep --line-buffered "Current pressure" | sed "s/^/$(date '+%H:%M:%S') | /"`

Every 5 seconds powermetrics prints out the current thermal pressure level so the output is:

```
12:37:59 | Current pressure level: Moderate
12:37:59 | Current pressure level: Moderate
12:37:59 | Current pressure level: Moderate
12:37:59 | Current pressure level: Moderate
12:37:59 | Current pressure level: Moderate
```

Not surprisingly I guess, sed is just using the pattern from the initial call to date so the timestamp isn't updating.

Is there a modifier for sed or an alternate method I can use to have the date correctly appended to the beginning of the line?  I tried a similar thing with awk but the same issue occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sed will evaluate the date command only once. You can use `awk` to achieve this

```sh
sudo powermetrics --samplers thermal | grep --line-buffered "Current pressure" | gawk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S |"), $0 }'
```

You can also eliminate `grep` command to buffer the lines by awk

```sh
sudo powermetrics --samplers thermal | gawk '/Current pressure/{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S |"), $0 }'
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I had tried awk but had used a different approach that hadn't worked.

Comment: `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` = `%F %T`. Also - sed isn't evaluating the date command at all, the shell is evaluating it before it calls sed passing it the output of the date command. All sed sees is `s/^/12:37:59 | /`.